# PyQt QVBoxLayout adding elements at bottom

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm a beginner learning Python/PyQt.
I'm trying to add `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`s to a `QVBoxLayout` however all the widgets get added at the bottom of the screen.

I've tried using `vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)` but that does not seem to work either.

Any pointers are appreciated!

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class m_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, scale = 1):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initUI(scale)

    def initUI(self, scale):
        #initialize window sizes
        win_width = app.desktop().screenGeometry().width() * scale
        win_height = app.desktop().screenGeometry().height() * scale
        #init widgets
        project_name_lbl = QLabel('<b>Project Name</b>', self)
        project_name_inp = QLineEdit(self)
        frameworks = ['Skeleton CSS','Bootstrap','UIKit','Foundation','JQuery']
        framework_cmbx = QComboBox(self)
        framework_cmbx.addItems(frameworks)
        #add items to layout
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch()
        vbox.addWidget(project_name_lbl)
        vbox.addWidget(project_name_inp)
        vbox.addWidget(framework_cmbx)
        #self settings
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Website Template Maker')
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(win_width, win_height))

    def run(self):
        self.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

m_Window(.5).run()
```

**pic:**

[image: <code>QVBoxLayout()</code> adding widgets to the bottom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the line

```
vbox.addStretch()
```

To after you've added your widgets:

```
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(project_name_lbl)
vbox.addWidget(project_name_inp)
vbox.addWidget(framework_cmbx)
vbox.addStretch()
```

This will make the layout push your widgets up instead of down.